# GCP Load balancing Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0 globally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

**Background 1**

In my account, the limited of Compute Engine API Backend services is increased to 75.
[image: -]

**Background 2**

I only have 9 Back-end service in Load balancing

**Question**

When I try to create a new Load Balancer, I receive below message:

> Quota 'BACKEND_SERVICES' exceeded. Limit: 9.0 globally.

Suppose I should have enough quota for creating new backend service.....

Except removing other backend service, any suggestion for fixing this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have two options: a) delete an existing backend b) request a quota increase so that you can have more than 9.

Comment: um....I have descript both your suggestion in my question, @JohnHanley

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. Regional quotas is new to me. Where can I find it? I only find global quota for backend service.

Comment: What does this link show? https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&metric=%22Backend%20services%22

Comment: @JohnHanley only one choice, Compute Engine API Backend services, and when click on All Quotas, it show same information as the image I attached in the question T.T

Comment: I think you need to resubmit your quota increase request. I have seen quotas be approved but not implemented. Explain the issue in your quota increase request.

Comment: @JohnHanley.....sadly....I just try to resubmit the request and state my issue inside the request, however, I only receive auto approved from google....

Comment: Request a large quota increase to trigger a human review.

Comment: funny, after I resubmit the request, I am now able to create new load balancer...thanks @JohnHanley, and, would you like to submit a new answer, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when a quota increase is approved, the deployment of that quota increase does not happen. I have experienced this several times.

My recommendation is to request a higher quota increase and explain the details about the previous quota increase being approved but not being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, it’s recommended to [request a higher quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota) for backend services, also I share with you the [backend services quotas](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#backend_services) that includes all backend services (INTERNAL, INTERNAL_MANAGED, INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED, and EXTERNAL) in your project.